# How to animate a frame change of a view in iphone when the super views are different...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation

I have a button on view1 and and I want to move it to view2 , but with animation from top. My view1 is on on the top half of the screen and view2 on the bottom half of the screen. So the superview changes as you can see. I have tried multiple approaches but the button just appears from the left or right but not from its origin. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have accomplished this very result using the following code:

```
CGRect tabFrame = tab.frame;
CGRect viewFrame = [mainWindow convertRect:tabFrame toView:currentView];
tab.frame = viewFrame;
[tab removeFromSuperview];
[currentView addSubview:tab];
```

This code converts `tab`'s frame from `mainWindow` into `currentView`.  This works perfectly, aside from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478204/cgrect-conversion-bug) bug.  If you don't encounter that problem, or find out how to solve it I would really appreciate that.

All you need to do from that point is apply your normal animation.

Answer (score 3):

Make the superview not clip their contents by setting [`clipsToBounds`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds) to `NO`.

Then you animate the button's frame and when the animation is done you remove it from view1 and add it to view2.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
    animations:^{
        button.frame = newFrame;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        CGRect rect = [view1 convertRect:button.frame toView:view2];
        [button removeFromSuperview];
        [button setFrame:rect];
        [view2 addSubView:button];
    }];
```

Comment: Seeing as how we have very similar responses, are there any advantages to moving the view AFTER the animation as opposed to BEFORE?

Comment: I don't think so. It just seemed logical to me this way.